# iphone app crashes after loading more row into a custom table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using a UITableView with custom cell. 
I have an array that contains the objects of class A. 
In cellForRowAtIndexPath i go though the array and assign each object to each cell. I first load 25 rows. Then when load more is pressed i load another 25 rows. When i move up and down i works fine. But problem happens when i load more 25 cells. When i move to the top of the table the app crashes. 
I debugged the app and found that the object that i assign from the array has value of 0xffffffff which means there is nothing. It always happens at the 4th cell of the table. 
Can anyone help me out why this is happening ??

thanx

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing in the console?  Often it's a good hint, but if it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you need to worry about memory corruption.

I have written this blog to understand crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS and how to debug them.

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

1. Run Build and Analyze -- fix the problems it reports
2. Run with Zombies enabled (instructions at link above)

Most problems are solved by doing those two things. Otherwise Debug Malloc (also explained at the link)

Comment: The thing is its not happening on the simulator. It is happening only on the device. I am sure its memory issue. I am a bit confused in solving this memory issue.

Comment: As soon as you have a memory problem, all bets are off.  It might not work on the device or simulator or both or neither.  If you turn on Zombies in the simulator, you might still find it -- it might not crash, but Zombies will still be flagged.

Comment: I enabled the Zombies and carried out the same steps i follow on device. But not matter how many cells i load its not crashing or flagging anywhere. Every time i load more data the array grows and after certain number of count the last few objects data gets out of memory since i for one of the object where it crashes the memory address i get is 0xffffffff

Comment: Are you leaking?  Use the Memory Leak instrument to check

Comment: I tried the instrument to check for leaks and i found lot of leaks where responsible library are mainly ImageIO and CoreGraphics. All the leaks are mainly related to image and its placeholders. Also i found that the app is not crashing on the device when running performance tools.